# Change Right Bar Button Items on Current Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have spent all day trying to figure this out and I'm beyond frustrated.

I have a navigation stack and on each screen, based on the content of the screen, I need to hide/show some of the right bar button items. But no matter what I do, the items are changing on the previous screen on the stack, not on the current screen.

My view controllers are all pushed onto a navigation controller. And each view controller can instantiate another view controller and push onto the navigation stack.

```
let vc = UnifiedArticleViewController()
        
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I have tried the following:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems = [arrayOfBarButtonItems]
```

and:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [arrayOfBarButtonItems]
```

as well as a variety of other suggestions I've gotten from various stack overflow suggestions.

I have been able to change the title of screens using:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "New Title Here"
```

and that works perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [arrayOfBarButtonItems]` should work. Can you show the code for the how you are presenting the current view controller?

Comment: You should be able to update the title with just `title = "New Title"` from the viewDidLoad function. Is the view controller embedded in a navigation controller, or are you adding a navigation bar to the view controller itself?

Comment: @aheze I have added code for how I am adding view controllers to the navigation controller.

Comment: @James The view controller is embedded in a navigation controller. I have updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `leftBarButtonItems` or `rightBarButtonItems` from the controller you're wanting to set the button(s) on that is in the navigation controller's view stack.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Left", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(leftButtonPressed(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [leftButton]

        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(rightButtonPressed(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [rightButton]
    }
    @objc func leftButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    }
    @objc func rightButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. Inside the viewWillAppear of my view controller I'm trying to set the bar button items. They are not appearing on the current view controller. They are appearing on the previous view controller in the stack.

Comment: I don't know how you presenting the controller to be able to know what your issue is.  Trying setting the controller via the nav controller's top controller property `navigationController?.topViewController?.navigationItems = `

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. Thanks very much!